# Is there a C# equivalent for Java's NoSuchElementException?

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a C# equivalent for [Java's `NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)?

Comment: in what context would this be thrown?

Comment: .NET now supports NoSuchElementException handling.             catch (NoSuchElementException elem)
            {
                _log.ErrorFormatEx("No such element exists", elem);
            }

Comment: @John Threepwood check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580473/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-handling-exceptions-like-nosuchelementexception-for

Answer (score 5):

.NET usually uses `InvalidOperationException` for that. You should not catch `NoSuchElementException` anyway because it usually indicates a program bug. For that reason the concrete exception type does not matter that much in this use case.

Unfortunately, `InvalidOperationException` is used in many places for many different things. You often can't tell much from it. This is a flaw in the BCL's exception hierarchy.

Comment: You can tell quite a lot from `InvalidOperationException.Message` though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's not machine-readable. You can hardly catch any specific error in .NET without doing a `e.Message.Contains(...)`. This is soooo dirty. Positive examples such as socket error codes are the rare exception.

Comment: Well the point is really that you shouldn't be catching InvalidOperationException OR NoSuchElementException, other than to dump out the human-readable content to a log.

Comment: @MatthewWatson agreed.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) is used to indicate that the end of an enumeration has been reached:

> Thrown by the `nextElement` method of an `Enumeration` to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

The .NET Framework uses a different interface, where [`IEnumerator.MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) would return `false`, rather than throwing an exception, when the end of an enumeration is reached:

> If `MoveNext` passes the end of the collection, the enumerator is positioned after the last element in the collection and `MoveNext` returns `false`. When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent calls to `MoveNext` also return `false`.

**Edit**: Rawling correctly points out that issues might still arise if the `Current` property is accessed beyond the end of the collection. In such cases, the behaviour is not consistent. [`IEnumerator.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) states that an exception will be thrown; however, [`List<T>.Enumerator.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ztkdk88.aspx) states that the behaviour is undefined:

> For better performance, this property does not throw an exception if the enumerator is positioned before the first element or after the last element. The value of the property is undefined.

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: It appears that there isn't an equivalent exception. In .NET, **you must not ignore the state of the enumerator** (as identified, for example, through the return value of the `MoveNext` method), or you will run into undefined behaviour which could unpredictably break your application.

Comment: ... but calls to `Current` will probably need to throw an exception. (Edit: I see your point, the Java exception is explicitly thrown by the equivalent of `MoveNext`.) Edit edit: Actually it's not really equivalent, `nextElement` is a kind of "move next and return current". Confusing or what?

Comment: @Rawling: I've expanded my answer to address the `Current` issue.

Comment: That is an interesting point about the List enumerator. (Seemingly applies to a Dictionary enumerator as well - as hinted by the doc for List, which points to the wrong class!)

Comment: ...also applies to [`Array.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getenumerator.aspx). The .NET designers seem determined that users should not get away with ignoring the `MoveNext` return value.

Comment: Weird. [`IEnumerator.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) claims to throw an exception if `MoveNext` returned `false`, and indeed that is what happens if you try with an array's enumerator, even though the page you linked said it's undefined! The List and Dictionary enumerators seem to return `default(T)` instead of throwing.

Comment: ... but they also *explicitally* implement `IEnumerator.Current` with a getter that *does* throw an exception if it's out of range! Clever stuff.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer. .NET now supports NoSuchElementException  as I am now handling them with ease.

Comment: @AussieJoe: Which version of .NET?

Comment: @Douglas .NET 4.7 and Selenium.WebDriver 3.2.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.27.0

Comment: @Douglas You can also see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580473/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-handling-exceptions-like-nosuchelementexception-for

Comment: @AussieJoe: That is not an equivalent to Java's `NoSuchElementException`, which is thrown when enumerating past the end of a collection. Anyone could have defined and thrown an `NoSuchElementException` from their custom library for arbitrary scenarios.

Comment: @Douglas I see now, my apologies. Selenium has a NoSuchElementException in C#, and it's ported from Java. I hope these comments can help clarify for others. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Linq uses:

```
[InvalidOperationException]
```

With the message:

```
Sequence contains no elements
```