# Selenium WebDriver C# - Handling Exceptions like NoSuchElementException for each and every WebElement interacting statement?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Is it recommended to handle exceptions like NoSuchElementException for each and every statement which is involved in interacting with WebElement in my Selenium WebDriver script?

For example, if there is a page having hundred elements and I need to interact with each of them through Selenium WebDriver, so is it recommended that I need to add try catch block for each of them while interacting?

Answer (score 2):

If you are requiring that many try/catch wrappers for interacting with elements, you may want to consider a handy dandy wrapper function, something like this:

```
public IWebElement FindElement(By selector)
{
    // Return null by default
    IWebElement elementToReturn = null;

    try
    {
        // Use the selenium driver to find the element
        elementToReturn = Driver.FindElement(selector);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        // Do something if the exception occurs, I am just logging
        Log($"No such element: {selector.toString()} could be found.");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Throw any error we didn't account for
        throw e;
    }

    // return either the element or null
    return elementToReturn;
}
```

Not completely sure what kind of interaction you are trying to achieve with these hundreds of web elements so it's hard to tailor my answer to your exact purpose, but in this example I have the wrapper function returning null if the `NoSuchElementException` appears. From there you could use the [safe navigation operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx) to safely interact with an element that may or may not exist. For example:

```
FindElement(By.Id("my-back-button"))?.Click();

Assert.AreEqual("hello", FindElement(By.ClassName("greeting"))?.Text() ?? "");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. But my question isn't about how to use try/catch blocks for hundreds of web elements. Sorry if my question is not clear. But what I want to know is - should we handle exceptions for each and every web element interacting statement in the code. For example, I have n number of  statements interacting with n number of web elements like `FindElement(By.Id("my-back-button")).Click();` , 'FindElement(By.Id("my-back-button")).Text;` , etc. So, is it recommended to handle exception for all these statements? Or we can just leave these statements without handling exceptions.

Comment: I like to add customised exceptions when interacting with important elements. So if something important like clicking a Login button fails, rather than getting a NullReferenceException, I like to throw a custom LoginFailedException with a helpful message for testers.

For general element interaction though I would say try/catch statements everywhere are not necessary. If something fails, you'll find out anyways.

Comment: @BenChand Try/Catch is super useful for **logging**. Logging is super useful for **automated testing**.